# Synthesis of signal from Fourier transformation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I work at Matlab. I have function as graphic. I should:

1. expand it to Fourier series on paper,
2. reconstruct this function from my series,
3. reconstruct function from answer series (I have solving of Fourier series),
4. compare my reconstructed function with original.

```matlab
step = 0.05;
t = -5:step:10;
y1 = heaviside(abs(t)-6);
y2 = heaviside(-(abs(t)-2));
funct = 4*(y1+y2)+2;
plot(t,funct,'LineWidth',2),grid;
%coefficients of my Fourier series y
a = -4; b = 8; T = abs(a-b); L = T/2;
a0 = 8; 
a(1) = 2*sqrt(3)/pi;      b(1) = -2/pi;
a(2) = 6*sqrt(3)/pi;      b(2) = 3/pi;
a(3) = 0;                       b(3) = - 8/(3*pi);
a(4) = -2*sqrt(3)/pi;     b(4) = 3/(2*pi);
a(5) = -2*sqrt(3)/(5*pi);     b(5) = -2/(5*pi);
n = -5:step:10;
sum = 0;
for k = 1:5
    sum = sum + a(k)*cos(n*pi*k/L)+b(k)*sin(n*pi*k/L);       
end
y = a0/2 + sum;    %my series
%answer Fourier series y2
n = -5:step:10;
sum = 0;
for k = 1:5
    sum = sum + (power(-1,k-1)/(2*k-1))*cos((2*k-1)*pi*n/4);
end
y2 = 4+(8/pi)*sum;  %answer series
n = 1:length(t);
hold on
plot(n*step-5,y,'r-');
```

When I draw y (my reconstructed function) I have the following picture:
[image]

But when I draw y2 (answer function) I have good result:
[image: https://yadi.sk/i/03ysYoNKfaABe]

First graphic looks like I use only one Fourier component when reconstruct signal.

Why did I obtain such bad result for my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I couldn't escape the feeling that my first approach was wrong, so I was thinking further. Your program and the pictures are completely correct!

The difference is that in the 2nd loop `k=1` leads to a period length of 8 and a phase of 0 (i.e. the cosine starts at `x=0`) which nicely matches the underlying rectangular function.

But in the 1st loop the period length for `k=1` is slightly longer (and the phase is different from 0). The longer period length together with adding each cosine and sine component (and not only the odd ones as in the 2nd loop)
leads to an approximation which is not so obviously fitting the underlying rectangular function (but indeed it does as good as possible with this low number of coefficients). You need to use about 15 instead of 5 coefficients to get a similarly good fit as with the 2nd loop.

**Old and wrong debugging approach:**

My first guess was that the values for your coefficients `a` and `b` are wrong because the correct function is even and thus all sine amplitudes should be zero (*why!*).

To test if your 1st estimation loop is correct I took the coefficients from the 2nd loop

```
k = 1:5;
a = power(-1,k-1) ./ (2*k-1);
b = zeros(1,5);
```

and used them in the 1st loop instead of yours. The result was still wrong. 
So, to find the 2nd mistake you need to compare the lines

```
sum = sum + a(k)*cos(n*pi*k/L)+b(k)*sin(n*pi*k/L);
```

and

```
sum = sum + a(k)*cos((2*k-1)*pi*n/4);
```

If you want to debug on your own then stop reading now, otherwise my next hint is that `(2*k-1)` guarantees that only the 1st, 3rd, 5th, ... cosine gets an amplitude value different from zero (which is a necessary property of a rectangular wave).

Answer (score 1):

@Hartmut Pfitzinger, Thanks for your answer. I find another way to solve my problem: I considered function on (-4, 8) interval and it was no odd and no even. But I realised that I can consider function on (-2, 6) interval and it would be even. So I just expended signal to Fourier series on the interval (-2,6), found coefficients for cos only, and gain approximation as at 2nd loop.

Comment: That is also a possible way to go, and actually it is a follow up of my "Old and wrong debugging approach". It was "wrong" because it didn't exactly answer your question "Why did I obtain such bad result for my solution?" But I think my update gave the answer. So, I would be happy if you accepted it